# What is the "old religious formula" Nietzsche refers to?

Tags: nietzsche

> to employ once more an old religious formula with a new and deeper meaning--it is some fundamental certainty which a noble soul has about itself, something which is not to be sought, is not to be found, and perhaps, also, is not to be lost.--THE NOBLE SOUL HAS REVERENCE FOR ITSELF (*Beyond Good and Evil* #287).

So, I get the aphorism. But I can't figure out his source. Is there some saying in a religion that this comes from?

Comment: I'm not familiar with a religious source but that sounds like an echo of Kant's account of morality to me.

Comment: love and submission before the law (which i'd imagine is a fairly universal formula in religion) ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The religious formula in question could be the view that a person will be accepted by God not because of his *works* but because of his *belief*.

This view is expressed by the Christian apostle Paulus in several of his letters, e.g., Galatians 2.16, 3.10, Ephesians 2.8-9, Romans 4.4-6.

Nietzsche applies the formula without its religious context. He does not propagate belief in God but belief in oneself.

Comment: This is the correct answer imo: the formula that Nietzsche refers to directly _precedes_ the quote in the OP's question: "Es sind nicht die Werke, es ist der _Glaube_, der hier entscheidet, der hier die Rangordnung feststellt, um eine alte religiöse Formel in..." ("It's not the works; it's the _belief_ which decides here, which here establishes the order of rank, to take up once more an old religious formula...")

Comment: You are so right. I don't know how I missed this. It's not this excerpt at all, but the preceding context which he was referring to. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

Nietsche may be alluding to formulas of [Acquinas's theology](https://books.google.com/books?id=z4gRQ0bIhvUC&pg=PA132&lpg=PA132&dq=fundamental+certainty+which+a+soul+has+about+itself+-noble&source=bl&ots=89wxxi885O&sig=t9Ri-5-7xUbcWzhxzT7wE4hub2M&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CBwQ6AEwADgKahUKEwjS76D657HIAhUB0IAKHTP3DwQ#v=onepage&q=fundamental%20certainty%20which%20a%20soul%20has%20about%20itself%20-noble&f=false), where one reads that "*the science concerning the soul is most certain*" and "*mind is said to know nothing better than what is in itself*". Acquinas however refers to the utmost certainty about soul's own existence and content (the idea goes back to Augustine, and was famously appropriated by Descartes), whereas Nietsche has in mind a "new and deeper meaning".

Earlier in the chapter [What is Noble](https://www.marxists.org/reference/archive/nietzsche/1886/beyond-good-evil/ch09.htm) he mentions that "*the multitude... have on their part learnt great reverence--reverence for "great men"*". Alas, "*SUCCESS has always been the greatest liar... the "work" of the artist, of the philosopher, only invents him who has created it, is REPUTED to have created it; the "great men," as they are reverenced, are poor little fictions composed afterwards*". The reverence of works is therefore exposed as reverence of fakes. But by reverencing works artists and scholars betray a real longing, longing for nobleness. "*But this very NEED of nobleness is radically different from the needs of the noble soul itself, and is in fact the eloquent and dangerous sign of the lack thereof*".

And Nietsche has a remedy for this self-alienation. To satisfy the needs of the noble soul he suggests turning to the most fundamental certainty of all, the one from the "old religious formula", the certainty of self. "*It is not the works, but the BELIEF which is here decisive and determines the order of rank--to employ once more an old religious formula with a new and deeper meaning--it is some fundamental certainty which a noble soul has about itself, something which is not to be sought, is not to be found, and perhaps, also, is not to be lost.--THE NOBLE SOUL HAS REVERENCE FOR ITSELF.--*"

Answer (score 0):

> Can you be your own judge and avenger of your law? Terrible it is to
>   be alone with the judge and avenger of one's own law... Lonely one,
>   you are going the way of the lover: yourself you love, and therefore
>   you despise yourself, as only lovers despise.

In [Zarathustra section 17:](https://faculty.washington.edu/cbehler/teaching/coursenotes/Texts/Zarsel.html) On the way of the creator.

I think that he's talking about something entirely general to religion: the submission and love of (the divine) law which is oneself.